# Customize JDBC XA DataSource in IronJacamar

Tags: java, jdbc

I need help from IronJacamar experts.

My customer has an application whose JDBC DataSource are instantiated via IronJacamar. The config looks like this

```
    <xa-datasource jndi-name="jdbc/TaxDataSource" pool-name="TaxDataSourceDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">

            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>

            <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sbxtax</xa-datasource-property>
            <xa-datasource-property name="User">sbxtax</xa-datasource-property>
            <xa-datasource-property name="Password"></xa-datasource-property>
            <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
            </validation>
    </xa-datasource>
```

Now, we wish to replace the datasource class name with a sub class of XADataSource, which is also a wrapper of MysqlXADataSource. I guess that IronJacamar looks up for the 'data source factory' while instantiating the data source. However, i don't know how to register the factory class, even after scanning the IronJacamar documentation.

Could anyone let me know if what we attempt to do is feasible via config. And in that case, please show me the config for factory class.

Comment: You can find list of examples in samples that explain your question. I hope this helps!  http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.0/en-US/html_single/#sample_helloworld_mcf

Comment: That doc does not help. I had read it before posting this question